# Access the complete datatemplate of a list box

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 application wherein, I am using a listbox to show multiple details. My problem is, I want to access the datatemplate in code behind ie i want to get access to the complete datatemplate with access to all its children that are declared inside the datatemplate.

simply I want to change the visibility of an element that is inside the datatemplate of a listbox. Please give suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to update the DataTemplate this way? It won't change the currently created list items you can already see. It expect you actually want to data bind/update each list item individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `DataTemplate` that shows or hides certain elements based on the properties of the object it is bound to. One of the better ways to get this is to do something along the lines of:

```
class MyData
{
   ...
   public string Email {get {...} set {...}}
   ...
}
```

Since a user may or may not have an Email address your DataTemplate can use a converter to convert the string value of Email into a `Visibility` value that can be used to show or hide the field. The converter would look something like:

```
public class StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and you'd add a reference to it in XAML like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <this:StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Finally your `DataTemplate` would have a line that looked like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" Visibility="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource StringNotNullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Which essentially says "Show the email, but hide this field if the email is null".

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution over this problem

```
 public static T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        try
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
            if (count == 0)
                return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I used this method to find out the first element in my data template and then i changed the visibility of the element.
here is an example how to use this method..

```
ListBoxItem item = this.lstboxMedicationList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
 CheckBox tagregCheckBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(item);
 tagregCheckBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
lstboxMedicationList.UpdateLayout();

    here i is the index of ListBox item.
```